# opnecart 3.0.3.2 updated error Proxy::getGeneralSetting

Tags: opencart, account

Notice: Undefined property: Proxy::getGeneralSetting in /home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx/beta/system/engine/action.php on line 79
after updating opencart i ma getting this error in account section . kindly help

Comment: You need to give some detail about how you updated OpenCart? What method did you use?

Comment: normal method .. website url/install/ and upgraded to latest version